# How to get multiple data value from gallery

Tags: android, image, video

Now I am going on with the pick of multiple `images and videos` from gallery for that I am using   `intentgallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);` method to select multiple from gallery.

In `onActivityResult` how can I get the multiple selected values in list usually we will get the value of selected data by `intent.getData();` likewise how can we get the multiple data value tried a lot to get the value but can't.

No need of CustomGalleryActivity need it by default android intent.

If anyone have idea about this please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE
In onActivityResult you need to do like that:
ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();

And notice **Added in API level 18**

Answer (score 0):

Try below code on `onActivityResult` but below code support 18+ API.

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action))
        && Intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
    // get selected images
    ArrayList<Parcelable> images = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

    for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
       Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;
       // do something with images one by one here
   }
}
```